# How do I disable `console.log` inside QUnit tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, qunit

When running QUnit with Node.js (`npx qunit`), I would like to have the `console.log()` messages from the code being tested suppressed, as to not interfere with the output of QUnit.

Overriding `console.log` in the test will suppress all QUnit output. I am using QUnit v2.9.2.

Comment: That's tough... other than changing your source code to use a separate logger (like Winston) I'm not sure how you can do this.